# How to get the purchase status of a store add-on product on uwp

Tags: uwp, in-app-purchase

I have 2 items for users to buy, so they can unlock some premium functions.

At first, I can show the purchase window, and they can buy the add-ons. Then I can store a local variable to know the purchase status.

But if they uninstall and reinstall the app, how to know the add-on's purchase status silently? I tried

```
StoreContext context = StoreContext.GetDefault();
var result = await context.RequestPurchaseAsync("9NP83X0BQP20");
if (result.Status == StorePurchaseStatus.AlreadyPurchased)
    return true;
```

RequestPurchaseAsync method also pops up a window to buy again.

So, how to know the an add-on's purchase status silently just using his id, not the roaming data method?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> how to know the an add-on's purchase status silently just using his id, not the roaming data method?

You can use [Query for product](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/query-for-products) in Microsoft Store collection API to get all products that a customer owns for apps that are associated with your Azure Ad client ID.
To use this method, you must create a token with the `https://onestore.microsoft.com` audience URI and a token with the `https://onestore.microsoft.com/b2b/keys/create/collections` audience URI.
For more details , please refer to the official document: [Create Azure AD access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/view-and-grant-products-from-a-service#step-3-create-azure-ad-access-tokens) and [Manage product entitlements form a service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/view-and-grant-products-from-a-service).

**Update**

You can compare the product info of the purchased add-on and the product info of the current add-on to determine if the add-on has been purchased, there are two methods provided for you to get the purchased product info.

1.[StoreContext.GetUserCollectionAsync(IIterable) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storecontext.getusercollectionasync#Windows_Services_Store_StoreContext_GetUserCollectionAsync_Windows_Foundation_Collections_IIterable_System_String__) : It returns a [StoreProductQueryResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storeproductqueryresult) object that contains Microsoft Store info for the add-ons of the current app for which the user has purchased and relevant error info.

2.[StoreContext.GetUserCollectionWithPagingAsync(IIterable, UInt32) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storecontext.getusercollectionwithpagingasync#Windows_Services_Store_StoreContext_GetUserCollectionWithPagingAsync_Windows_Foundation_Collections_IIterable_System_String__System_UInt32_) : It returns a [StoreProductPagedQueryResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storeproductpagedqueryresult) object that provides access to the Microsoft Store info for the add-ons of the current app for which the user has purchased and relevant error info, as well as the next page of results.

Comment: Is there any simple method? I thought Microsoft should provide a direct simple method, just check the product id is purchased or not.